# How to pull the first date that apper in one task? Excel

Tags: excel

Hi I have this sheet that represent timeline for a task in a project. The task can have multiple under tasks (A, B, C etc.) See example;
[image]

I want to pull the first date that appear in the timeline(grey area) through all under tasks into another sheet that should show the first date from the timeline, in this case; 23-11-2023

so far I have used this line;
`=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(TRUE;NOT(ISBLANK('sheetname'!B3:Z3));'sheetname'!B3:Z3);"No date")`
this line only gives me the first date in row 3, but not all grey areas.

Can I do this without VBA?

Comment: 23.11.2024 does not exist in the data shown. 23.11.2023 does and so does 26.11.2023 but nothing for 2024.

Comment: If you manually colored that grey area, you will need VBA to search in colored area. Unless there is rule based on data which cells should be grey.

Comment: Just drag/fill your formula down. The row reference will update and return the appropriate date for that row. If you have MS 365 you can use the `BYROW` function to return all the results with a single formula.

Comment: `=@TOROW(B3:Z3,3)` possibly?